# shorter jquery code for div width animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, width

I am trying to write a jquery code for animating div width change on hover, I don't want to use css because I want to be able to support older browsers. 
I wrote this jquery code for expanding and shriking the div on mouse hover/mouseout:

```
$('.menu').hover(function(){
    $('.menu').animate( { width: "350px" }, 400 );
});
$('.menu').mouseout(function(){
    $('.menu').animate( { width: "50px" }, 400 );
});
```

this is the div css:

```
.menu { height: 500px; width: 50px; }
```

I am not sure, but the Jquery code feels a bit to long for such a simple action, is there a way to make it shorter?

thanks in advance, Eyal.

Answer (score 3):

what about

```
$('.menu').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        width: e.type == 'mouseenter' ?
            "350px" : '50px'
    }, 400);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M7W6L)

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly well. I must admit that I have very basic knowledge in jquery, so I don't know how to use functions in an advanced way...

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below

```
$('.menu').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate( { width: "350px" }, 400 );
},function(){
    $(this).animate( { width: "50px" }, 400 );
});
```